# How to detect browser and device support for gyro and accelerometer in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, accelerometer, gyroscope

I have a website that produces a VR experience using 360 photos.

Recently Apple updated the iOS to 12.2 and turned off safari's access to the "motion and orientation" sensors by default.

So I need to add a section of javascript that will detect if the gyro and accelerometer are available and to prompt the user to enable access (if available).

I've found two earlier code suggestions on stackoverflow that are designed to detect support for these sensor, but when tested on my iPhone 6s with iOS 12.2 both solutions report that no gyro is present, which is not the case. And yes, access to the motion and orientation is on.

Here's an example from a previous solution.....

```
var canHandleOrientation;
if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {
    window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", handleOrientation, false);
}

function handleOrientation(event){
  console.log("Orientation:" + event.alpha + ", " + event.beta + ", " + event.gamma);
  canHandleOrientation = event; // will be either null or with event data
}

if (!canHandleOrientation) {alert("There is no gyroscope")
```

In this test script there is an alert "There is no gyroscope" that should appear if there is no data from a gyro.  Since the iPhone 6s has a gyro I would not expect to see the message appear, but it does.

Comment: Where did you get that code from? It is nonsense as the event callback is not called instantly and the `if` clause is thus executed before that.

Comment: Not very used to this API myself, but are you sure this is how the code was written? It is listening for an `deviceorientation` Event to fire in order to  set `canHandleOrientation` flag (asynchronously set then), but the code is checking this same flag synchronously. There is no way that any device would ever have a truthy `canHandleOrientation` at this moment.

Comment: This code came from a 2012 stackoverflow page entitled "Testing hardware support in Javascript for device orientation events of the iPhone 3GS"